# Why the _directory function is called four times in a yeoman.generators.Base subclass?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Here is how I extend the yeoman generator `Base` class

```
module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  prompting: function () {
    var done = this.async();

    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the cool ' + chalk.red('generator-zeetings') + ' generator!'
    ));

    var prompts = [{
      ...  
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
      this.props = props;
      // ...
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  _directory: function (source, destination) {
      // Simplified for this question
      var src = path.join(source, 'index.html');
      var dest = path.join(destination, 'final.html');
      console.log('Copy from ' + src + ' to ' + dest);
      this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath(src),
        this.destinationPath(dest),
        this.props
      );

  },

  prepareApp: function () {
    this._directory(this.templatePath(), this.destinationRoot('app'));
  },

  prepareData: function () {
    this._directory(this.templatePath(), this.destinationRoot('data'));
  },

  writing: function () {
    this.prepareApp();
    this.prepareData();
  },
});
```

I find that for some reason the helper function `_directory` is called 4 times.

I expected the function is called only twice, one for `app` and the other for folder `data`, by the `writing` function.

It turns out if I prepend `_` to `appendApp` and `appendData`, the generator will behave as I expected.

What I want to understand are:

1)  I don't seem to find this behaviour documented on yeoman website. Is this behaviour ('calling every public method in the subclass') expected?

2) If this is an expected behaviour, how can i control the order these public methods are called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the documentation: http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html

Each function in a yeoman-generator is a task. Tasks are all run automatically and ordered based on their priorities (priority is defined by the function/object name).

Functions names starting with an underscore are considered private and won't be runned.